# I got an error when I tried to create a new React Native project using the command npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

```
Apples-iMac:React Native apple$ npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
Need to install the following packages:
react-native@0.72.5
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/3ec76935
npm ERR! dest /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9b/6d/3fb6c175ae11947aadbe72a2bd1a47fc51c94d8c5723e703f7391b987af885f65fe9e27cbb138e45616240491a95d46b973d5915027da8485d29e1c59859
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcompat-data: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/3ec76935' -> '/Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9b/6d/3fb6c175ae11947aadbe72a2bd1a47fc51c94d8c5723e703f7391b987af885f65fe9e27cbb138e45616240491a95d46b973d5915027da8485d29e1c59859'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9b/6d/3fb6c175ae11947aadbe72a2bd1a47fc51c94d8c5723e703f7391b987af885f65fe9e27cbb138e45616240491a95d46b973d5915027da8485d29e1c59859
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T07_14_04_855Z-debug-0.log
```

I am following the steps to set up React Native, but I am getting an error. I do not understand what the error means, and I need help fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This by adding `--f`

`npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject --f`

OR

`npm install -g react-native-cli` 
`npx react-native init Yourappname`